# javascript assign image to span with alt text

Tags: javascript

I work with javascript

I didn't find how can I assign image to span and add alt text to this image

I have this code :

```
<a href="testUrl" >
  <span id="101"></span>                                    
</a>
```

This is the code javascript :

```
var pic = "C:\image1.jpeg"; 
var img = new Image(); 
img.src=pic ;
var defautValue='10'
var nbrInc='(';
nbrInc=nbrInc.concat(defautValue,img,')');  
document.getElementById("101").innerHTML=nbrInc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/dxbv69uq/

```
var pic = "http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg"; 
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var e = document.createElement("img");
    e.setAttribute("src", img.src);
    e.setAttribute("alt", "title");
    document.getElementById("101").appendChild(e);
}
img.src=pic;
```

Answer (score 0):

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/ksmon7u6/)

```
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "http://img.zohostatic.com/discussions/v1/images/defaultPhoto.png");
elem.setAttribute("height", "768");
elem.setAttribute("width", "1024");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
document.getElementById("101").appendChild(elem);
```